# Is it possible to have Unity search any child containers if a resolution fails?

Tags: c#, unity-container

I have a unity container with a number of registrations.  I then create a child container and add some more registrations.  The child container is meant to contain a specific group of registrations that have a different lifetime than those in the parent container and the child container may be disposed of at any time.

Now when I try to resolve a class which has some constructor dependencies from the parent container and some from the child container, the resolution fails since it cannot find any of the dependencies that are defined in the child container.

Is there any way, via some unity extension or something, that I can have the resolution call attempt to search child containers if it fails on the parent container?

For example:

```
//Some class that setups up unity
class Init()
{
  ...
  _container.RegisterType<ICar, BMW>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
  var childContainer = _container.CreateChildContainer();
  _childContainer.RegisterType<IPlane, Boeing>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
  ...
}


class TestClass
{
  //Fails because only ICar is able to be resolved
  public TestClass(ICar car, IPlane plane){...}
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is to have singleton types that are registered that I can dispose of when I choose to (for example when a view is closed).  So first thing that came to mind was to group those types in a child container with `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager` and then I can dispose of the container as I see fit, leaving the ones that I still want to keep untouched in the parent container.  Perhaps there is a better approach but I am not sure.

Comment: Why do you want to resolve the classes with the parent container when you actually want to resolve them with the child container you are specifically setting up for that purpose? Wouldn't it make more sense to work with the child container directly?

Comment: Ideally yes, it would be straight forward in that case, but based on how the larger project I am working on is setup, when classes are being resolved the main, parent container is automatically used for the dependencies.  Unfortunately I may not be able to change that so was wondering if there were any other options.

Comment: How do you want to decide which child container is used, if you can retrieve a list of all the child containers?